# WordPress: Ajax request value not being returned in add_filter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using the Give plugin, and I'm trying to write some test code to pass along a new value at checkout.

I'm trying to pass along a value to a filter with an Ajax request, but the filter does not take the new value, only the original value.

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'test');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'test');    

$test_amount = 400; //Initialize variable with test amount.

function test(){

    global $test_amount;

    $test_amount = 200;
    echo $test_amount; //Confirm I'm echoing 200 when test() is called via Ajax (it is)
    wp_die();
}

function give_basic_fees_add_fee($test_amount) {

    global $test_amount;
    return $test_amount; // This is returning 400 when it should be returning 200

}

add_filter( 'give_donation_total', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee', 1, 1 );
```

Also, I would like tips on how to achieve this without using `global` if possible.